# How to key off a parameter to a stubbed method using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, mockito

Greetings.

I am mocking a search engine for testing in my web app. This search engine returns xml documents with different schemas. The schema depends on a parameter known as a collection set. Returning different schemas based on collection sets is the part that's difficult to mock, because specifying the collection set is basically a setup method, and a void one at that. This search engine is an external jar file so I can't modify the API. I have to work with what's been provided. Here's an example:

```
Engine engine = factory.getEngine();
Search search = engine.getSearch();
search.addCollectionSet(someCollectionSet);
SearchResult result = search.getSearchResult();
Document[] documents = result.getAllDocuments();
```

Then for each document, I can get the xml by calling:

```
document.getDocumentText();
```

When I'm using my mock objects, `getDocumentText()` returns an xml string, created by a generator, that conforms to the schema. What I want to do is use a different type of generator depending on which collection set was provided in step 3 in the first code snippet above. I've been trying to do something like this:

```
    doAnswer(new Answer() {
        Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            if (args == "foo") {
                SearchResult result = getMockSearchResult();
                when(search.getSearchResult()).thenReturn(result);
            }
        }
    }).when(search.addCollectionSet(anyString()));
```

But this results in lots of red highlighting :)

Basically, my goal is to key off of `addCollectionSet(someCollectionSet)` so that when it's called, I can do some kind of switch off of the parameter and ensure that a different generator is used. Does anyone know how I can accomplish something like this? Or is there maybe some form of Dependency Injection that could be used to conditionally wire up my generator?

Thanks!

**Update**

I've changed my factory object so that it never returns the engine, but rather, the Search and Find objects from that engine, so now I can do something like this:

`Search search = factory.getSearch(collectionSet);`

So what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
when(factory.getSearch(anyString()).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
    Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        switch(args[0]) {
            case fooSet: return fooSearch; break;
            case barSet: return barSearch; break;
```

In other words, I still want to key off the string that was passed in to getSearch in a switch statement. Admittedly, I could do something more like felix has suggested below, but I'd rather have all my cases wrapped in a switch. Can someone provide an example of how this could be done? Thanks!

**Update**

I've seen that you can capture the arguments that are passed into mocked calls, but these captured arguments are used for later assertions. I haven't seen a way that I can key off these arguments so that a call to my mock will return different values depending on the arguments. It seems like there has to be a way to do this, I just don't have enough experience with Mockito to figure it out. But surely someone does!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend wrapping the call to the legacy code into your own object. 
So you end up with your own method along these lines:

```
class SearchEngineWrapper {
  public String getSearchResult(String collection){
    Engine engine = factory.getEngine();
    Search search = engine.getSearch();
    search.addCollectionSet(someCollectionSet);
    SearchResult result = search.getSearchResult();
    ...
    return document.getDocumentText();
  }
}
```

Now you can mock out this method. The method also nicely documents your intent. Also you could test the actual implementation in an integration test.

```
when(searchEngineWrapper.getSearchResult("abc").thenReturn("foo");
when(searchEngineWrapper.getSearchResult("xyz").thenReturn("bar");
```

Comment: if I were to do something like this, I'd like to replace "foo" with anyString(), but doing a switch off of that string is proving to be tricky. Do you know a good way to do this? If so, could you update your example?

Comment: Arguably trying to create two interacting mocks is an awkward thing. It doesn't make much of a difference, whether you mock third party code or your wrapper around the third party code, does it? I also updated the example)

Comment: I have found a way to do something like you're suggesting which works better for us, but I'd still like to know if there's a way to use the anyString() method and do a switch off of the string that's used. Thanks.